# Generic list of generic lists

Tags: c#, generics

I've been playing with various ways of using generics and have hit a road block.

Consider the following classes:

```
public abstract class DataElement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class School : DataElement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
    
public class Course : DataElement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
    
public class Student : DataElement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Phone { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Considering a hypothetical scenario where none of this data changes, I'm trying to create a DataDictionary class to house those objects in their respective Lists all within one top-level List property. This crazy idea came to me, when I was writing code to load the different data types from JSON files. I was able to write one load method that could read all three types of data using generics, and that sent me down this particular rabbit hole.

```
public interface IDataDictionary
{
    public List<T> GetAllItemsFromList<T>();
    public T GetSingleItemFromList<T>(int id);
}

public class DataDictionary : IDataDictionary
{
    public List<IList> Data = new List<IList>();

    // Return all objects from the list of type T
    public List<T> GetAllItemsFromList<T>()
    {
        return Data.OfType<T>().ToList();  // This works, returning the appropriate list.
    }

    // Return specific object from the list of type T by Id property value
    public T GetSingleItemFromList<T>(int id)
    {
        List<T> list = Data.OfType<List<T>>().First();  // This works, resolving to the correct list (e.g. Courses).
        return list.Where(i => i.Id == id).First();  // This doesn't work. It doesn't appear to know about the Id property in this context.
    }
}
```

GetAllItemsFromList works fine, returning the appropriate list of items

```
List<School> newList = GetAllItemsFromList<School>();
```

However, I am unable to figure out how to return a single item by Id from its respective list.

```
School newSchool = GetSingleItemFromList<School>(1);
```

It could be that I'm just trying to be too clever with this, but I can't help but think there is a way to do this, and I'm just missing it.

Comment: Why does everything inherit from `DataElement`  then proceed to ignore/not use  the `Id` they inherit?

Comment: Following Nyssa's input, all that would be needed is to initialize the super class Id. Is there an error message?

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp Good catch. That was an oversight on my part. I implemented the abstract class, trying to get this to work, and merely neglected to remove it from the inheriting classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This doesn't work. It doesn't appear to know about the Id property in this context.

Yes, because you have not specified any [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) to the type parameter `T`, so it can be anything. There are multiple options:

- Create an interface `IHaveId` and constraint `T` to it (or use `DataElement`):

```cs
public interface IHaveId
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IDataDictionary
{
    public List<T> GetAllItemsFromList<T>();
    public T GetSingleItemFromList<T>(int id) where T : IHaveId; // or where T : DataElement
}

public class DataDictionary : IDataDictionary
{
    public T GetSingleItemFromList<T>(int id) where T : IHaveId // or where T : DataElement
    {
        List<T> list = Data.OfType<List<T>>().First(); 
        return list.Where(i => i.Id == id)
            .First(); 
    }
}
```

- add additional parameter to select the id:

  ```
    public T GetSingleItemFromList<T>(int id, Func<T, int> idSelector)
    {
        List<T> list = Data.OfType<List<T>>().First(); 
        return list.First(i => idSelector(i) == id);
    }
  ```
- use reflection - I would argue the least recommended option

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was missing. I've gotta say, I'm beginning to love generics.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that T parameter in function `GetSingleItemFromList<T>(int id)` could be anything. In order of this to work you should add a constraint:

`GetSingleItemFromList<T>(int id) where T: DataElement`